# Flatlist wont updated after input data React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flatlist

I made one screen that contain flatlist about accounts detail, when I input new data in other page and go back to that screen using navigation.navigate(), it still showing the last screen, not the updated one. Any advice on this?

```
const [childData, setchildData] = useState([]);
function readFunction(){
        db
        .ref('childData/'+ userID)
        .once('value', snapshot => {
            var childNameVal=[];
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                childNameVal.push({
                    nameVal: child.val()['childName'],
                    idChild: child.val()['idChild'],
                })
            })
        setchildData(childNameVal)
        });
    }
```

```
<FlatList
                data={childData} 
                renderItem={renderItem} 
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.idChild}
                vertical
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            />
```

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <View style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
            <Pressable 
                style={styles.baby_box}
                title={item.nameVal}
            >
                <Text>{item.nameVal}</Text>
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable 
                style={styles.btnDelete}
                value={item.idChild}
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate('MainNavigator',{
                        idChild: item.idChild
                    });
                }}
            >
            <Text style={styles.btnText}>Pilih</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    );
```

Comment: How do use get back to the previous screen ? When  and how is the readFunction triggered ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:
The screens maintain their last state until you update them** intentionally.

You have to update the data yourself by having some updating logic.
Following are the solutions.

1. Reloading the screen when you want to. (Recommended)

---

**a. Navigation.navigate.**

It pushes new screen if it doesnt exist in navigation stack. If it   exists it will act as pop and pass the paramaters to it. Which you can use to update the array.

**b. Redux**
If you have already integrated redux and using it. Them you can have some "reloadScreen: boolean" paramter in reducer which you can toggle whenever you call reload action

2. Reloading the screen when you come back on it.

---

**Reload screen on focus**

When you come back to previous screen it will reload data.
Drawback of this it will always reload data even if you haven't change any thing on next screens.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

function ProfileScreen({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // reload your Data
        reloadData()
    });

    // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <View />;
}
```

Comment: thank you, solved. quick question, can I use this reload on specific component only? or it will reload the whole screen?

Comment: you can reload a specific component by placing a state inside that functional component.
But it makes the state only accessible on that function only because its defined in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

Inside your component:

```
const isFocused = useIsFocused() 
useEffect(()=>{
if(isFocused){
readFunction()
}
},[isFocused])
```

This will call the readFunction everytime your screen gets focused, that is every time you navigate to the screen.

Comment: i also try ur suggestion and it work, thanks bro